# c++ inline assembly optimizations

Tags: c++, inline-assembly

Why Visual Studio C++ compiler doesn't optimize by default the following piece of code?

```
#include "ctime"
#include "iostream"

#define BIG_NUM 10000000000

int main() {

    std::clock_t begin = clock();

    for (unsigned long long i = 0; i < BIG_NUM; ++i) {
         __asm
        {
            nop
        }
    }

    std::clock_t end = clock();
    std::cout << "time: " << double(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

    std::cin.get();
}
```

Without the `_asm` block, operation time is always 0, because loop is *"skipped"* entirely due to compiler optimizations. With the `_asm` block it takes few seconds instead.

Is there any compiler flag to optimize inline assembly or for some obscure reasons it isn't possible?

Comment: It's not obscure, asm blocks are just treated as basically black boxes.

Comment: c compliers don't try to understand what is inside the asm blocks, they just put them in the right position inside their own assembly code and then forward all to the assembler

Comment: When you add an `__asm` block it assumes that you know what you're doing (which may not be the case) and has no idea what you might do inside of it, which prevents it from doing optimizations.  Otherwise you would end up with very unpredictable code.  It's not unusual for compiled code to have a very non-obvious structure/code order to take advantage of pipelines and other processor optimizations.  Your inline assembly throws a wrench into that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The compiler doesn't really understand inline assembly, and thus assumes it could do anything.

Generally inline assembly is used when you specifically want to optimize some code at a low level. And if you're doing that, why do you expect the compiler to further optimize it?

Answer (score 0):

Adding some more information to the accepted answer

1) There are *some* compilers which can optimize across inline asm - the Xbox 360 compiler could but these are likely the exception rather than the rule.

2) There are some tools which run optimization on the compiled binary [e.g. here](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/cse/bit_projects.mspx) - these are likely to be able to be able to optimize inline asm.

3) Finally, and probably most appropriately, one of the most popular reasons to add inline asm is to hand roll math heavy vectorised SIMD routines which are too complicated for the compiler to do on its own. If you want this then a much better way would be to use [intrinsics](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/). Intrinsics give you the best of both worlds - you can hand roll your tricky routines and THEN let the compiler handle register allocation, unrolling, interleaving, dead code pruning, etc for you.

For a good example for intrinsics see the examples below - if 'INLINE_ASM' is defined it takes ~300ms else it is optimized to nothing and takes 0 ms even though they do a similar thing.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    auto tc = ::GetTickCount();

    for(int i=0; i<1024 * 1024 * 1024; ++i)
    {
#if INLINE_ASM
        _asm
        {
            paddw xmm0, xmm0;
        }
#else
        _mm_add_epi16(__m128i(), __m128i());
#endif
    }

    std::cout << "Took " << ::GetTickCount()-tc << " milli-seconds!" << std::endl;
}
```